# Type CCC doesnt conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, nsobjectprotocol

I don't understand why my code doesn't work. Here it is:

```
class Test: NSURLSessionDataDelegate {

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {

        if(error == nil) {
            print("Hallo")
        } else {
            print(error?.userInfo)
        }
    }

    func createRequest() {

        let dictionary = [
            "mailAddress":"foo@example.com",
            .....
        ]

        let nsData: NSData?
        do {
            nsData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue:0))
        } catch _ {
            nsData = nil
        }

        let defaultConfigObject = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: defaultConfigObject, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        let url = NSURL(string: "http:...")!
        let urlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        urlRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        urlRequest.HTTPBody = nsData
        urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let dataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest)
        dataTask.resume()

    }
}
```

And the error:

> Type Test does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you follow up the inheritance chain, `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` inherits `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate`, which inherits `NSURLSessionDelegate`, which inherits, `NSObjectProtocol`.  This protocol has various required methods like `isEqual(_:)` and `respondsToSelector(_:)` which you class does not implement.

Generally what you would do here is make your class inherit `NSObject` which conforms to `NSObjectProtocol`:

```
class Test: NSObject, NSURLSessionDataDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I mistyped `NSObject` as `NSOBject`, because if you mistype it, then it isn't technically conforming to `NSObject`.  Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make my class conform to protocol `FBSDKSharingDelegate` and got the same error. When I tried to make my subclass with superclass `UIView` conform to the protocol, the error went away.

Comment: That's because `UIView` already inherits `NSObject` (via `UIResponder`).